# UE4 Visual C++: Translate a compiler generated lambda name to its location in code

Tags: c++, visual-c++, lambda, unreal-engine4

I have a crash callstack log that's failing on a lambda expression named `lambda_10d422b71bd9aaff182f55a71df28fd9` every time. I'm wondering if its possible to use a debugger (preferably visual studio's debugger) to translate this lambda's name to its actual location in my project's source code.

For further context, here's the full crash callstack. I'm using Unreal Engine 4.25 compiled in visual c++, of course:

```
ProjectName!TWeakBaseFunctorDelegateInstance&lt;ACoreCharacter,TTypeWrapper&lt;void&gt; __cdecl(void),&lt;lambda_10d422b71bd9aaff182f55a71df28fd9&gt; &gt;::Execute() [d:\src\unrealengine\distrib-full\engine\source\runtime\core\public\delegates\delegateinstancesimpl.h:1097]
ProjectName!FTimerUnifiedDelegate::Execute() [d:\src\unrealengine\distrib-full\engine\source\runtime\engine\public\timermanager.h:51]
ProjectName!FTimerManager::Tick() [d:\src\unrealengine\distrib-full\engine\source\runtime\engine\private\timermanager.cpp:881]
ProjectName!UWorld::Tick() [d:\src\unrealengine\distrib-full\engine\source\runtime\engine\private\leveltick.cpp:1626]
ProjectName!UGameEngine::Tick() [d:\src\unrealengine\distrib-full\engine\source\runtime\engine\private\gameengine.cpp:1686]
ProjectName!FEngineLoop::Tick() [d:\src\unrealengine\distrib-full\engine\source\runtime\launch\private\launchengineloop.cpp:4856]
ProjectName!GuardedMain() [d:\src\unrealengine\distrib-full\engine\source\runtime\launch\private\launch.cpp:169]
ProjectName!GuardedMainWrapper() [d:\src\unrealengine\distrib-full\engine\source\runtime\launch\private\windows\launchwindows.cpp:137]
ProjectName!WinMain() [d:\src\unrealengine\distrib-full\engine\source\runtime\launch\private\windows\launchwindows.cpp:268]
ProjectName!__scrt_common_main_seh() [d:\agent\_work\2\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:288]
kernel32
ntdll
```

For further Unreal Engine context, this is crashing from a weak lambda bound to a timer. I'm trying to figure out which specific weak lambda is failing. The only other option I have is to have QA generate a crash dump - but that might take hours.